# Variable in JavaScript, why putting `var` does not work?

Tags: javascript

When I put `var` in front of `method` and `url` (`var method`, and `var url`) the code does not work.

```js
function intervalcheck(theObject) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = 'POST',
    url = 'https://thekmui.com/payb/payresult/result.php';

  xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
  xmlhttp.onload = function () {
```

Comment: Because `var a = 1, var b = 2;` is invalid syntax. Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Why would you expect invalid syntax to work? `var a = 1, b = 2;` is correct syntax. Use [Fetch](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of `XMLHttpRequest` and use `const` or `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at here:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = 'POST',
```

You are putting ','(comma) after each line. Either you leave it empty and browser handle the rest. Or you can put ';' semi-colon like this:

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    method = 'POST';
```

Otherwise the code will produce a massive error.
You may follow this post as well:
[Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)